# Are Avallorex's robes an existing magic item?

Tags: magic-items, pathfinder-2e, content-identification, intelligent-magic-items

The newly released Lost Omens: Knights of Lastwall book from Paizo includes a fair bit of information about the enigmatic gnome seer Avallorex. One bit that stood out to me was this line:

> "He wears a tattered gray cloak that moves of its own volition, interposing itself between harm and acting as an additional hand."

Is this an existing magic item with stats? It appears similar to the (mild spoilers for Strength of Thousands)

> Graveknight Captain's Shield

But that item can't be used by Avallorex by its own nature. Is there any appearance of a rune or specific magic clothing in Pathfinder that could autonomously shield the wearer from harm and allow them to hold something as if they have a third hand? If not, are there any effects that (spoilers for Knights of Lastwall)

> A Morrigna could use to replicate these apparent effects?

Comment: Seems more like a Dr Strange reference than a mechanical item to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Intelligent Snagging Dueling Cape

Most [intelligent items](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1092) are able to take actions independently of the partner/wearer.

> As a default, intelligent items have control over all their own magic, meaning... intelligent items perform their own activations when they wish. Intelligent items can typically use 3 actions per turn, acting on their partner’s turn. These actions don’t count toward their partner’s 3 actions. They have a reaction if any of their activations requires one.

*[Snagging](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=1390)* is an accessory rune that allows the user to Grab an Edge without a hand free, so an intelligent cape can use its own magic to help its partner in this way. Not exactly a complete extra hand, but this seems to be the closest in function that has been published to date.

Finally, the [dueling cape](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=680) allows the user to effectively raise it like a shield by holding it in a protective position, where the intelligent cape can act protectively on its own.

Comment: I'm inferring this to mean that the actual item doesn't exist but this is a good approximation using what is available?

Comment: Yep, these existing elements could form a version of this generically described item, as "moves of its own volition, interposing itself between harm and acting as an additional hand".